# How to track the users activity on video portal?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I would like to know the users activities and have the track for the same. For example: If will take the example of youtube, I want to know:

1.How many users are new?
2.How many are existing?
3.What are the activities they are performing? (i.e. categories of videos they have gone through, how long they have spent time on each, what are the categories are frequently searched etcs.)

Comment: Off topic and too braod and unclear. Combo x3.

Comment: hi can you tell me plz

Answer (score -1):

Since you've tagged `java-ee`, one of the constructs that can help you is the WebFilter. You can create a Filter and map it with the Web URLs that you want to track - for example you can match it with certain servlets or JSPs that you would like to keep track of, or you can match the URL to all pages using `/*`.

Take a look at this [documentation from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html).

Here's an empty Filter implementation:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;

@WebFilter("/*")
public class SampleFilter implements Filter {

    public SampleFilter() {
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // place your code for capturing analytics here

        // pass the request along the filter chain. don't remove this!
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Use the `doFilter` method above to place your logic of capturing analytics. You  can use the `init` method to do some initializations. It pretty much works like a servlet.

The `@WebFilter("/*")` annotation takes care of registering the class as a Web Filter in the Deployment descriptor. Plus it also maps all requests as it has the `/*` URL mapping.

You can also use 3rd party tools like [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/) to do some of this.

Hope this helps!